# selenium to click on hyperlink which does not having unique property

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am using c# selenium webdriver for web ui automation. We have Html table on UI and that table is like below

```
Checkbox's            Status       Links
1st Checkbox         completed    *Get Document*
2nd Checkbox          Completed    *Get Document*
```

we have above two "Get Document" hyperlink .....but both having exactly same property as below

Get Document

i have used x path , and perviously shared code but not getting any luck ...please share any idea ...how to identify and click on such link when those having same name and same property

Please let me know if i am missing something.............

Comment: If "it is very urgent", you could have done a better job with your question, that required quite a bit of editing to make it at least a bit presentable. Also if you get an exception, **any information on it is relevant**. Like the full message and stack trace. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and more specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [edit] your question accordingly, if you want to have a better chance of getting an answer that helps you.

Comment: You will find that an XPath expression directly targeting the row you need will be the better option here. It will cut down on the amount of looping and iterating you'll need to do.

Comment: To add to what Alex said, if you've previously shared code related to this and you're not going to post it here, at least a link to the previous question would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your specific scenario, I'd do something like

`//tr[@id='checkbox1']/a[contains(@id, 'DocumentLink')]`.

However, if you have questions about xPath in general, [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) is a great place to start.

Comment: this is nice //tr[@id='checkbox1']/a[contains(@id, 'DocumentLink')]. .............but id is not fixed alwyas changing for that ...then what to add

Comment: It really depends on what's available.  If you'd include the HTML of the objects we're interacting with, I could probably provide a better example.